# WebChannelFactory calling WCF method configured with WebInvoke Method=GET throws ProtocolException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm having a problem calling a WCF method marked with WebInvoke Method='GET'.
Here is my code:

The WCF host:

```
            var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8099/hello");

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseUri))
        {
            var serviceEndpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            serviceEndpoint.Name = "WebHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService";
            serviceEndpoint.Contract.ConfigurationName = "HelloWorldService.IHelloWorldService";

            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior{HttpGetEnabled = true});
            serviceHost.Open();

            //Keeps it open
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseUri);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            serviceHost.Close();
        }
```

The service Contract:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/SayHello")]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SayHello", Method = "GET")]
    string SayHello();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SayHelloTwo", Method = "POST")]
    string SayHelloTwo(string name);
}

public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, Whatever");
    }

    public string SayHelloTwo(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm calling the methods:

```
            WebChannelFactory<IHelloWorldService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IHelloWorldService>(new Uri("http://localhost:8099/hello"));
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        var sayHelloTwo = channel.SayHelloTwo("Claor");
        Console.WriteLine(sayHelloTwo);

        var sayHello = channel.SayHello();
        Console.WriteLine(sayHello);
```

My problem is that when I call channel.SayHello(); it throws a Exception like this:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.

It happens both with the [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SayHello", Method = "GET")] and the [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/SayHello")].
But if I use [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SayHello", Method = "POST")] it works fine, as you can see in the method bellow.
Problem is that I really need that method to be a GET method, because ocasionally I'll need to call it via browser.

I'm starting to believe that WebChannelFactory simple won't work with GET methods. Is that it? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your time.